# I'm trying to make a slash command handler in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to change my command handler to work with slash commands, but I get Invalid Form Body error when try to turn on the bot.
I didn't want to have to switch handlers as that's what I use on all my bots, but I can't fix bugs either. I'm using discord js v13

This is my current command handler (`index.js`):

```js
const pComandos = fs.readdirSync('Comandos');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.description = new Discord.Collection();

for (const folder of pComandos) {
    const file = fs.readdirSync('Comandos/' + folder);

    for (const comando of file) {

        let cmd = require(`./Comandos/${folder}/${comando}`);
        commandsArray = [];

        console.log(chalk.green(`[ C ] O comando ` + chalk.bold(comando) + ` foi carregado!`))

        client.commands.set(cmd.help.name, cmd)
        if (cmd.help.description) {
            cmd.desc = true
            cmd.help.description.forEach(desc => client.commands.set(desc, cmd))
        }
        client.commands.set(cmd)
        commandsArray.push(cmd.help.name);

        if (cmd.init) cmd.init(client)

        client.on("ready", async() => {
            const server = await client.guilds.cache.get("892210305558532116")
            server.commands.set(commandsArray)
        })
    }
}
```

`Comandos/uteis/ping.js`

```js
const discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  
  var latency = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp

  message.reply(`<:emoji_3:892431734203891722> | My ping is: ${client.ws.ping}.\n | Timezone: ${process.env.TZ}`);

};
exports.help = {
  name: "ping",
  description: ["p"]
};
```

And the error:

```js
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
0.name: This field is required
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\whash\OneDrive\Documentos\optiPC-BOT2\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:349:13)     
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\whash\OneDrive\Documentos\optiPC-BOT2\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)   
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (C:\Users\whash\OneDrive\Documentos\optiPC-BOT2\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:146:18) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/909489088904712223/guilds/892210305558532116/commands',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: [
      {
        name: undefined,
        description: undefined,
        type: undefined,
        options: undefined,
        default_permission: undefined
      }
    ],
    files: []
  }
}
```

Comment: your getting a bad request response because for slash commands you need to atleast have a name for it which as stated in the error you don't have, not really sure since you don't import slashcommand from discord.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [`ApplicationCommandData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ApplicationCommandData) object.

Instead of this:

```js
commandsArray.push(cmd.help.name)
```

Do this:

```js
commandsArray.push({
  name: cmd.help.name,
  description: cmd.help.description.join("") // or whatever description you want
})
```